# Map Reduce: Wordcount don't make anything

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, java-6

I want to write my own word count example using MapReduce and hadoop v. 1.0.3 (I'm on MacOS) but i don't understand why it doesn't work
Sharing my code :

**main:**

```
package org.myorg;

import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.DoubleWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.MapWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextOutputFormat;

public class WordCount {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JobConf conf = new JobConf(WordCount.class);
        // set job name, mapper, combiner, and reducer classes
        conf.setJobName("WordCount");
        // set input and output formats
        conf.setInputFormat(TextInputFormat.class);
        conf.setOutputFormat(TextOutputFormat.class);
        // set input and output paths
        //FileInputFormat. setInputPaths(conf, new Path(input));
        //FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, new Path(output));
        FileOutputFormat.setCompressOutput(conf, false);
        conf.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        conf.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
        conf.setMapperClass(org.myorg.Map.class);
        conf.setReducerClass(org.myorg.Reduce.class);
        String host = args[0];
        String input = host + "/" + args[1];
        String output = host + "/" + args[2];
        // set input and output paths
        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(conf, new Path(input));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, new Path(output));
        JobClient j=new JobClient(conf);
        (j.submitJob(conf)).waitForCompletion();
    }
}
```

**Mapper:**

```
package org.myorg;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import java.util.TreeMap;
import java.util.Vector;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.ArrayWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.DoubleWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.MapWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Writable;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapReduceBase;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.OutputCollector;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Reporter;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.Context;

public class Map extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable>  {
    private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
    private Text word = new Text();

    @Override
    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value,
    OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter)
    throws IOException {

        MapWritable hs = new MapWritable();
        String line = value.toString();
        StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line);
        while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
            word.set(tokenizer.nextToken());
            //hs.put(word, one);
            output.collect(word,one);
        }
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

**Reducer:**

```
package org.myorg;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.math.RoundingMode;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.Vector;

import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.MapWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapReduceBase;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.OutputCollector;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Reporter;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.Context;


//public class Reduce extends MapReduceBase implements Reducer<Text, MapWritable, Text, Text> {
public class Reduce extends MapReduceBase implements Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, Text> {
    public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<IntWritable> values, OutputCollector<Text, Text> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
        int sum = 0;
        while (values.hasNext()) {
            sum += values.next().get();
        }
        String host = "hdfs://localhost:54310/";
        String tmp = host + "Temporany/output.txt";
        FileSystem srcFS;
        try {
            srcFS = FileSystem.get(new URI(tmp), new JobConf());
            srcFS.delete(new Path(tmp), true);
            BufferedWriter wr = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
            srcFS.create(new Path(tmp))));
            wr.write(key.toString() + ":" + sum);
            wr.close();
            srcFS.close();
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //   context.write(key, new IntWritable(sum));
    }
}
```

The Job started and end with no error but didn't write the output file.
I launch the jar with Hadoop with this command:

```
./Hadoop jar /Users/User/Desktop/hadoop/wordcount.jar hdfs://localhost:54310 /In/testo.txt /Out/wordcount17
```

This is the output:

```
2014-03-03 17:56:22.063 java[6365:1203] Unable to load realm info from SCDynamicStore
14/03/03 17:56:22 WARN mapred.JobClient: Use GenericOptionsParser for parsing the arguments. Applications should implement Tool for the same.
14/03/03 17:56:23 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
14/03/03 17:56:23 WARN snappy.LoadSnappy: Snappy native library not loaded
14/03/03 17:56:23 INFO mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
```

I suppose the problem is "unable to load native-hadoop library" but works fine for other Jar's.

Comment: Anything coming up in job tracker? "unable to load native-hadoop library" - is not the problem.

Comment: why have you commented context.write in reducer?

Comment: Also, please post the entire output of the MapReduce code. I only see the output until the Map process is about to begin

Comment: I have put all the output, map and reduce don't start!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Q : The Job start and end with no error but don't write the output-file ??**

Ans : I am not sure that job successfully ends w/o error .

**Problems :**

- **Job Configuration**:

  ```
  conf.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
  conf.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
  ```

> The setOutputKeyClass() and setOutputValueClass() methods control the
>   output types for the map and the reduce functions, which are often the
>   same. If they are different, then the map
>   output types can be set using the methods setMapOutputKeyClass() and
>   setMapOutputValueClass().

The Output class in your case is :

```
Map key : Text
Map Value : IntWritable 
Reduce key : Text 
Reduce Value : Text
```

Which will result in `Type mismatch exception`

- **Reduce**

I am not sure why you are using hdfs API to write your output to a file ?.

Should use `output.collect(key,value)`.

In case of multiple reducer are you handling the simultaneous write operation?
And I wonder what context.write is doing in old apis (it's commented )? .

---

You can use following for more information

**Debug your map-reduce Job :**

- [Counters](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.2.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Counter.html)
- [Jobtracker web interface](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2009/08/hadoop-default-ports-quick-reference/)

---

***Q. Difference b/w SubmitJob() && waitForCompletion() ?***

Ans : SubmitJob() : submits the job and ends .

waitForCompletion() : submits the job and prints the status of the job on console . 
So waitForCompletion() is SubmitJob()+status update of job until complete.

---

**word count**

Please read

- [Map Reduce Apache](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/mapred_tutorial.html)
- You can also find  `hadoop-examples-X.X.X.jar` in your installation folder.
- Go through `$HADOOP_HOME/src/expalmes/`  for source code .

---

> **$HADOOP_HOME = hadoop installation folder

Comment: I suppose my first code don't work because is deprecated and i have make some trobule. I have post new code in Edit1.

Comment: Deprecated had nothing to do with job fail

Comment: For statuts means the output of the job or what? Now I also look in src/examples

Comment: status = the state of the job . Try it to see

Comment: If i give the command "j.submitJob(conf).waitForCompletion();" or the coomand "j.submitJob(conf); the output of my another programe is done but i don't lock the progress of map & reduce (Map 0% Reduce 0% ecc), why?